# How do I find the number of elements between indices?

Tags: matlab

I have the following array of stock price highs by week (each element is for a particular week):

```
    5.7627
    6.0100
    5.8198
    5.8198
    6.0671
    6.0671
    6.0100
    5.5916
```

I need to find the number of periods since the 5-day high has occurred. For example, 5-day high are as follows:

```
    5.7627
    6.0100
    6.0100
    6.0100
    6.0671
    6.0671
    6.0671
    6.0671
```

To do this, I used:

```
x = movmax(high,[n-1 0],'omitnan')
```

However, I don't know how to calculate an array that finds the weeks since these figures occurred. The expected output would be something like:

```
0
0
1
2
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

Comment: Your question doesn't look like it has to do with the problem... Can you clarify? It seems  you want to repeat an element in an array until you find a bigger element, then you repeat the new element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
t = cumsum([true; diff(x)~=0]);
u = sparse(1:numel(high), t, true);
result = nonzeros(cumsum(u).*u)-1;
```

---

Using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
t = cumsum([true; diff(x)~=0]);
result = accumarray(t, t, [], @(u){(0:numel(u)-1).'});
result = cell2mat(result);
```

---

Using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (this approach requires more memory than the preceding ones, because it builds an intermediate square matrix the size of the data):

```
t = cumsum([true; diff(x)~=0]);
result = sum(triu(t==t.')).'-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using just plain good old programming?

```
price=[5.7627
6.0100
5.8198
5.8198
6.0671
6.0671
6.0100
5.5916];

M = price(1); % max in the list
M_ind = 1; % index where M happened
n_weeks = zeros(size(price)); % output
for k=2:numel(price)
    if price(k) > M
        M = price(k);
        M_ind = k;
    else
        n_weeks(k) = k-M_ind;
    end
end

disp(n_weeks)
```

ouputs

```
0
0
1
2
0
1
2
3
...
```